# How can I get the various local date formats using luxon js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, luxon

It's very well documented on how to format a date in various forms; however, I could not see documentation on getting the various date formats, i.e. short date, long date, time etc either from user's local settings or by specifying a country.

i.e.

short date format: `dd/MM/YY`
long date format: `d MMMM YYYY, dddd`

I will pass this format string to another component so that it can format it accordingly.

If it makes a difference, I am using React and Material-UI and will pass the formatting to `DatePicker` component.